# 動画や音声以外の独自バイナリをライブ配信する方法

Tags: ffmpeg

オンライン対戦ゲームの観戦システムを構築するため、キー入力が記録された独自バイナリをリアルタイムでアップロードしながら不特定多数の観戦者にライブ配信することを考えています。

[video.jsでHLS配信をやってみた - Qiita](https://qiita.com/t114/items/c7fdffaa2e7fdf406a7b)

こちらを参考に、CentOS7.5にてffmpegを利用して、mp4動画ファイルをHLS形式で配信させるテストには成功しました。

このような仕組みを応用して、独自バイナリを配信したいと思っているのですが、ffmpegは独自バイナリのエンコードには対応していないように見受けられます。

独自バイナリをmp4形式に偽装する何がしかの対応を行うべきなのか、そもそもHLSを使うべきではなく、別の方法を使うべきか、アドバイスいただけないでしょうか。

ポイントとしては、観戦が始まった時点では、対戦が終了していないので、試合中のキー入力のアップロードと観戦者への配信を、ほぼリアルタイムで行いたいということです。

Comment: 「独自バイナリ」について、もう少し具体的に説明を追記してもらえませんか？ / `ffmpeg`としては対応フォーマットが決まっているはずで、素性の分からない独自バイナリをどうやってエンコードするつもりなのか？ / 仮にエンコードせずそのまま配信できたとして、クライアント側で再生できるのか？…など不明な点が多いです。

Comment: @cubick 独自バイナリは、ある程度の単位でまとめられたキー入力の塊が、対戦中に定期的（例としては10秒間隔）にゲームサーバに送られてくるイメージです。配信のイメージは、ゲームサーバ側でクライアントが受け取れる何がしかの方式（できればhttpベース）に変換して、クライアントに配信し、クライアントがキー入力をもとに、対戦状況を描画することで再生するというイメージです。このことからわかるように、動画として再生されなくても構わない状況です。現在は、独自バイナリであるがゆえに、ffmpegで変換できない状況となり詰まっています。今後のアプローチとしては、ffmpegで変換できるように独自バイナリを動画データとして偽装する（なにがしかのヘッダ情報を付与すれば偽装できる？）か、HLS形式にこだわらない、独自のライブ配信システムを実装するかのどちらかかなと思います。おそらく後者の方が現実的ではと考え始めていますが、後者の場合は、WEBサーバのどこかのディレクトリに、定期的に送られてくるキー入力を何がしかの命名規則に基づきファイル名を別にして保存し、クライアントは命名規則に従いながら、順番にhttpアクセスでファイルを順番に取得する形が良いのでは？と思っています。ただ、既に汎用的な仕組みがあるようにも思いますので、何か良い解決方法があればアドバイスいただけると嬉しいです。

Answer (score 2):

この質問を切っ掛けに調べたところでは WebRTC という技術があるそうで、とっても複雑だけど小規模なら無料でも使えるサービスパッケージにまとめた人たちが居て、SkyWayという名前で提供されているようです。

こんなスライドがありました。
[究極のゲーム用通信プロトコル “WebRTC”](https://www.slideshare.net/rotsuya/webrtc-60167675)
[オンラインゲームの仕組みと工夫](https://www.slideshare.net/imaifactory/ss-48388661)
[細かくて伝わらないWebRTC(APIとか)](https://www.slideshare.net/iwashi86/webrtcapi-112712583)

他に商用のWebRTC SFU Soraを作っている人たちがWebRTCの資料を以下のようにまとめています。
[WebRTC コトハジメ](https://gist.github.com/voluntas/67e5a26915751226fdcf)
[詳解 WebRTC](https://gist.github.com/voluntas/a9dc017ea85aea5ffb7db73af5c6b4f9)
[WebRTC の未来](https://gist.github.com/voluntas/59a135343538c290e515)

上記の中で、「データチャネル」とか「シグナリング」というキーワードに関連する技術が、お探しのものに該当しそうです。

---

ちなみに、ゲーム配信プラットフォーム「Steam」で、フレンドのプレイを視聴する Steamブロードキャスト というサービスがベータテスト状態です。これもWebRTC技術を使っているようです。
[Steamブロードキャスト](https://steamcommunity.com/updates/broadcasting)

別のアプローチで、こんなのもあるようです。
[HTML5ゲームにもeスポーツの熱狂を。 Liberappに観戦APIとデモゲームを追加](https://prtimes.jp/main/html/rd/p/000000011.000031562.html)

Comment: たくさんの関連情報ありがとうございます。組み込めそうなものを確認の上、検討したいと思います。